# Laptop matrix parameters like wide color gamut, white variation, haze?

Tags: laptop, displays

I am not sure I truly understand what these specs mean for a laptop LCD matrix:

- Wide color gamut
- White variation
- "Haze" 44%

Which values are better when picking a screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified explanation of each specification and their effect:

**Wide Color Gamut (WCG)**: This simply is a qualitative measure of the number of colors the LCD display can use as opposed to the standard [Rec.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) gamut. This generally means more vibrant colors, as opposed to a standard display. This is because:

1. The color palette itself bigger.
2. It uses a higher bit depth (8bit, 10bit, etc.), which signifies how many steps of each color a TV has available.

You should use a LCD display with a WCG for a better picture and color fidelity. If this isn't necessary then go for a standard Rec.709 gamut.

**White variation**: It is the difference in luminance of the LCD at different spots of the LCD screen. Refer to this note:
[image]

Thus, a higher white variation means difference in the white brightness in individual spots of a fixed viewing angle. This should be the lowest possible for visual accuracy.

**Haze**: This refers to [Reflective Haze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haze_(optics)#Reflection_Haze). Haze is the measure of how much reflections are diffused.  A higher haze rating usually means an anti-glare coating which is increasingly matte. This generally makes colors less pop out, but with a decrease in reflections. 
Here is a comparison picture of different levels of haze and the effects on reflections and color: 
[image]

Generally, under high ambient light, a higher haze is better for increased readability and visual acuity. If there is little chance of reflections or no ambient light is needed, then the haze percentage doesn't need a higher than 25%, which increases apparent color accuracy.

Comment: Is it correct to say that haze reduces the colors but increases the contrast? (I am looking at the difference LP173WF1-TLB5 vs B3, panelook.com...)
Also, matte surface = -100 value in contrast?